# Problems with Regex in C#

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

In C# I'm trying to search an input string to find the preprocessor directive **#include** using Regex.

```
string searchpattern = @"\b#include\b";
```

but without any luck.

If I modify my input string to remove the '#' and only look for **include**, using

```
string searchpattern = @"\binclude\b";
```

all works perfect. Thinking '#' has some special meaning in Regex, I tried to escape it

```
string searchpattern = @"\b\#include\b";
```

but still no luck.

On another note, I am also having problems matching pointer declarations in my input string, for example **char***, with

```
string searchpattern = @"\bchar\*\b";
```

If someone could shed some light on what I am doing wrong I would appreciate it.
Thanks!

Comment: Give us a sample string and the exact code you use to match your regex.

Comment: By the way, `#` is used for comments within a regex: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#miscellaneous_constructs

Comment: @JuliánUrbano The comment syntax is `(?#`, not any `#`

Comment: @Barmar *`# [to end of line]`:The comment starts at an unescaped # and continues to the end of the line* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#miscellaneous_constructs

Comment: Right. But that's only in X-mode, aka free-spacing mode, indicated with `(?X)` at the beginning: http://www.regular-expressions.info/freespacing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\b- Matches a word boundary, that is, the position between a word and a space. But # is not the boundary of a word. Why don't you try below:

```
^\s*\#include\s
```

Comment: Alright! So there is the generic '\s' character. I like this approach. This way there is no problem with '#' which couldn't be used because it is not a word character, a requirement for '\b' to work. For my purposes I removed the '^' in front, just in case there is a block comment before the #include directive. Thumbs up to you (but also to Ron).

Answer (score 0):

You can't match your expression at the beginning of a line with word boundary `\b` only.

If you need to ensure it's at a word boundary OR at the beginning of a line, use:

```
@"^(?:\s*)(\#include\b)"
```

You may also need to escape `#` as `\#` like you have there, it's been a while for me using C# regex though, so try with both.

Comment: Yours fails if #include is NOT at the beginning of a line

Comment: @RonRosenfeld you're right.. sheesh. Honestly though, it SHOULD be at the beginning of the line. Updated to include space.

Comment: Well, if it SHOULD be at the beginning of the line, then ^#include\b should work.  If it might be in the middle of the line, looking for entries in the wrong place, then something like:  (?:^|\s)#include\b might be more appropriate.  And btw, \b does work at the beginning/end of line, if the adjacent character is a Word character

Comment: @RonRosenfeld riight, it's been a long day and I totally missed that. But in this case, since you'd never put #include after anything other than whitespace, it should be suitable.

Comment: This works but is too complicated for my needs. I don't fully understand this expression (not your fault). I hoped for something simpler.

Comment: @PeteD it's actually pretty simple, and will get you the most accurate results. Explained: `^` match beginning of line only, `(?:___)` is just a fancy capture group that says *don't include in result*, `\s*` matches 0 or more whitespace, and then your original include statement with a `\b` word boundary on the end. Play around with it here: http://regex101.com/r/lJ1cQ1

Answer (score 0):

@"#include\b"

The problem in your regex is the \b at the beginning.  \b represents a word boundary, and a word boundary is the junction of a word character and a non-word character (or the beginning/end of the line if the adjacent character is a word character).  Word characters are [A-Za-z0-9_].  Since **#** is not a word character, unless it is preceded by something in that character class, your regex will fail.  Most likely, the # is preceded by a space or the beginning of the line.

Your 2nd question has the same problem:

```
string searchpattern = @"\bchar\*\b";
```

In this case, the problem is the word boundary token after the asterisk, which is a non-word character.  Knowing this issue, you should be able to correct it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for this. I see my problem, now I realize that the '#' is not "compatible" to work with '\b'.